# One Windows account, multiple computers logged in

Tags: windows, login

Let's say I have three Windows PCs, each one running Windows 8.1.

I have one Windows account, qwe123@outlook.com.

My question is:

Can I log in to qwe123@outlook.com on each of those computers **at the same time**, or do I need separate accounts for each machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume they are Microsoft Live accounts as that is the most viable option and most relevant to this question.

You can login with such account at the same time on multiple computers, but do note that these computers *will share* settings such as the desktop background, and that when one pc changes this the changes may carry to the next depending on who logs out last.

But more important to know: you do not actually need to login/create a live account.

Upon first sign in press `Create account`, then at the bottom it will say `I do not want to create an account, create local account instead` (something along these lines anyway). Click it and you only have to supply a username and optionally a password. Settings are then only kept locally.

Answer (score -1):

You can login to any number of devices at the same time with your windows account. If you have skydrive, even your files will get synced.